# State of support for the optional fixed width integer types introduced in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 has finally introduced fixed width integer types in `<cstdint>`, as documented here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

It is stated that the types int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t and their unsigned variants are only optionally supported:

> (provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)

My question is to which extent these types are supported on current versions of compilers that claim to support C++11 (of MSVC, GCC, MinGW, clang, etc) and if this is alos supported on mobile OS's like Android and iOS. For example, Visual Studio 2013 and 2015, seem to support all of the types from `std::int8_t` to `std::int64_t` including unsigned ones. Is there any common compiler with C++11 support out there that does not support these types (or does it wrong, according to the C++11 spec) - or can these types, for example, be used in a cross-platform library without having to worry?

Comment: MSVC, Clang and GCC for x86 and x86_64 definitely support all of them. Don't know  about ARM though

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the response. With the links to prove it and info about ARM, this would already be a sufficient answer

Comment: Any C++11 compiler is expected to support them if they exist in the hardware. If you have a 36-bit architecture, you may not have int32_t.

Comment: @n.m. Source? I would like to read more on this.

Comment: "These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names." (C99 7.18)